# Remove columns from pandas DataFrame that are not integers and outside specified numerical range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that has imported data. However, the imported data can be incorrect and so I am trying to get rid of it. An example DataFrame:

```
    user    test1    test2    other
0   foo       1        7       bar
1   foo       2        9       bar
2   foo       3;as     5       bar
3   foo       3        5       bar
```

I want to get clean up columns `test1` and `test2`. I want to get rid of values that are not within a specified range and those that contain a string by some error (as shown above as the entry `3;as`). I am doing this by defining a dict of acceptable values:

```
values_dict = {
    'test1' : [1,2,3],
    'test2' : [5,6,7],
}
```

and the list of column names I wish to clean:

```
headers = ['test1', 'test2']
```

My code as it stands right now:

```
# Remove string entries
for i in headers:
    df[i] = pd.to_numeric(df[i], errors='coerce')
    df[i] = df[i].fillna(0).astype(int)

# Remove unwanted values
for i in values_dict:
    df[i] = df[df[i].isin(values_dict[i])]
```

But it seems that erroneous values are not removed to form a desired dataframe of:

```
    user    test1    test2    other
0   foo       1        7       bar
1   foo       3        5       bar
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why is the row with *test1 == 4* kept? it's not in the acceptable range either?

Comment: Typing error on my part - thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this; use `np.logical_and` to construct the `and` condition from multiple columns and use it to subset the data frame:

```
headers = ['test1', 'test2']
df[pd.np.logical_and(*(pd.to_numeric(df[col], errors='coerce').isin(values_dict[col]) for col in headers))]

#  user  test1  test2   other
#0  foo      1      7     bar
#3  foo      3      5     bar
```

*Break down*:

```
[pd.to_numeric(df[col], errors='coerce').isin(values_dict[col]) for col in headers]
```

firstly converts interested columns to numeric type and then check if the column is in specific range; which makes a boolean series for each column:

```
#[0     True
# 1     True
# 2    False
# 3     True
# Name: test1, dtype: bool, 
# 0     True
# 1    False
# 2     True
# 3     True
# Name: test2, dtype: bool]
```

To satisfy conditions from all columns simultaneously, we need an `and` operation, which can be constructed further using `numpy.logical_and`; use `*` here to unpack all columns conditions as argument.

Comment: Excellent explanation, thank you. It appears to be filtering my data properly now!

Comment: Cool. Glad it helps.